# Why is adding table row not working using JQuery and asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When I click my button, nothing happens.

```
$("#<%=btnAddCategory.ClientID %>").click(function () {
  $('#tblCategoryTemplate').find('tbody').append('<tr><td>aaa</td><td>ddd</td></tr>');  
});
```

```html
<table id="tblCategoryTemplate">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Template</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>ddd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<asp:TextBox id="txtNewCategory" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Button id="btnAddCategory" runat="server" Text="Add Category" OnClientClick="Return false;" />
```

Comment: Have you debugged this at all? Is the event handler being fired? Any errors in the console? It looks like the `runat="server"` attribute on the button will be causing a postback, so any JS on the button will be redundant as the page gets reloaded/transferred on button click.

Comment: Is you js in your asp page or in a js file?

Comment: because this `$("#<%=btnAddCategory.ClientID %>")` is not a element on the page

Answer (score 2):

Your JQuery code just works. I think you have asp.net postback issue since misspelled `return` in [`OnClientClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick):

`OnClientClick="Return false;"`

Should be:

`OnClientClick="return false;"`